# Erro: Object reference not set to an instance of an object no ExportDocumentAsync DxRichEdit Devexpress blazor

Tags: devexpress, blazor

Tenho 2 textos, um para editar o modelo e um para ver o texto completo, ao editar o texto do modelo e clicar para ver o texto completo, é invocado o método do LostFocus do DxRichEdit, dentro do método tenho uma chamada do ExportDocumentAsync(DocumentFormat.Rtf)

`DocumentContent = await richEditModel.ExportDocumentAsync(DocumentFormat.Rtf);`

, porém ele da erro de null reference, alguem sabe oq pode ser?

```
Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.